# Hyperledger Fabric Difference between user's privileges

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

If I have 1 organization `orgA`, and under this organization I have 2 user: `user1` and `user2`, also there is 1 peer in `orgA`, lets call it `peer0`.

Now imagine, `user1`'s certificate is in `orgA's` `msp/admincerts` forlder, that makes `user1` admin for `orgA`. On the other hand lets say `user2's` certificate is in `peer0's` `msp/admincerts` folder, that makes `user2` admin for `peer0`.

My question is what is the difference in privileges between `user1` and `user2`, I mean what `user1` can do and what `user2` can't do and vice versa?

Also I am using `fabic ca` and `node sdk` to interact with network. In my example when I enroll fabric ca's bootstraped user (admin/adminpw) from nod sdk, and then make create channel request, it worked, but then when I make join channel request it failed (because this user don't have privileges). When I tried to understand why this happened, I discover that if I make join request from user that's certificate is not in peer's msp/admincerts folder, that kind of user don't have permission to make peer to join channel. So only way is I have to copy enrolled admin's certificate into peer0's msp/admincerts folder, then I think it will work, but is it an only way to make it work, or is there any other way to avoid copy/paste and to it from sdk, or create new configuration update transaction?

Also I can't understand what makes this user capable of creating channel? what permissions does bootsraped user from `fabric ca`  has?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late reply but hope someone may find this helpful. The user roles and the permissions aren't directly linked, this is done through the policies set in the `configtx.yaml`.

Policies are defined for each Org and Orderer, marking each of the member and admin to a certain set of policy subgroup like `Readers` or `Writers` or `Admins`.These are the grassroot level policies used to construct ImplicitMeta policies like for chiancode query and write.

For example, an org defines policy like

```
# Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies: &org1Policies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org1.example.com.member')"
                # If your MSP is configured with the new NodeOUs, you might
                # want to use a more specific rule like the following:
                # Rule: "OR('org1MSP.admin', 'org1MSP.peer')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org1.example.com.member')"
                # If your MSP is configured with the new NodeOUs, you might
                # want to use a more specific rule like the following:
                # Rule: "OR('org1MSP.admin', 'org1MSP.client'')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org1.example.com.admin')
```

The Policies for the consortium is defined like:

```
Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
```

This references the org and orderer policies defined earlier.

Now in the system chaincode can have policies like:

```
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    ACLs: &ACLsDefault
        #This section provides defaults for policies for various resources
        #in the system.
    #---Query System Chaincode (qscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        #ACL policy for qscc's "GetChainInfo" function
        qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByNumber" function
        qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers
```

Here the policies referenced point to consortium policies.

Please read [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/policies.html) for more detailed guidance on this.